# How to filter aggregation results in elasticsearch (v 6.3)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an array for field commodity line ex:[3,35,1,11,12],[3,12]. I am trying to query the field for autocomplete results and i need output as 3 and 35 when i match with 3. My indexing works fine for all the scenarios except when i am working with an array data type.

I will need to filter the aggregation results to give 3 and 35, which i am unable to retrieve.i need to use facet_filter or filter with prefix .Similar to facet.prefix in solr.
Let me know if i need to change the query or the mapping? 
Query :

```
GET contracts/doc/_search
{
 "size":0,
 "query":{
   "bool":{
     "must":{
       "match":{
         "commodity_line.autocomplete":"3"

       }
     }

   }
 },
"aggs" : {
  "names":{
    "terms":{
      "field":"commodity_line.keyword"
    }
  }

    }
}
```

Mapping :

```
   PUT contracts
        {

           "settings":{
              "analysis":{
                 "filter":{


                "gramFilter": {

                     "type":     "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram" : 1,
                    "max_gram" : 20,
                  "token_chars": [
                    "letter",
                   "symbol",
                    "digit"
                  ]
                }

              },
                 "analyzer":{


                      "autocomplete": { 
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "trim",
                    "gramFilter",
                     "asciifolding"


                  ]
                }




                 }
              }
              }

           ,
           "mappings":{
              "doc":{
                 "properties":{
         "commodity_line" :{
                       "type":"text",
                      "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      },

                      "autocomplete":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "analyzer":"autocomplete", 
                      "search_analyzer":"standard"
                      }
                      }


                   }
        }
        }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an solution, 
I had to match it with a prefix rather than filtering the results.

```
"aggs" : {
  "names":{
    "terms":{
      "field":"commodity_line.keyword",
 "include" : "3.*"
    }
  }
```